# Node OPCUA Server and async setters for a value

Tags: asynchronous, server, setter, node-opcua

I'm using both client and server from node-opcua, it's working fine apart for error management on the server side when the client tries to write a value and something goes wrong. In order to improve that, I'd like to have an asynchronous setter like in this example:

```
        const wantedValue = namespace.addAnalogDataItem({
            componentOf: node,
            browseName: `${chamber}${folder}Req`,
            nodeId: `s=${chamber}${folder}Req`,
            dataType: "Double",
            engineeringUnits: settings.unit,
            engineeringUnitsRange: settings.range,
            value: {
                get: () => new Variant({dataType: DataType.Double, value: wrapper.readProgram(chamber, folder)}),
                set: async (variant: Variant) => {
                    const success = await wrapper.writeProgram(chamber, folder, variant.value)
                    return  success ? StatusCodes.Good : StatusCodes.Bad
                }
            }
        })
```

This naive approach lead to a typer error:

```
    throw new Error("Cannot find StatusCode " + statusCode);
```

Is there a better way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

- the get and set lambdas are design to be synchronous.
- you need to use the callback form with timestamped_get and timestamped_set to achieve what you need.